# Using CASE statement in SUM() In Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my code:

```
BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(
       CASE WHEN first_name > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS a 
       CASE WHEN last_name > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS b,             
       CASE WHEN country > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c, 
       CASE WHEN state > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS d, 
       CASE WHEN city > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS e)
    AS total
    FROM employee_profile     
    WHERE id = user_id_in;

END
```

This generates the following error:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near xxx error for the first line.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax for this, please?

MySQL Server version: 5.5.8

Comment: "Can anyone help with the correct syntax for this" - that would depend on what you are trying to do, which you have neglected to mention...

Comment: @MitchWheat : I am trying to sum.  The problem is that I cannot get the SP to compile.  Example:  In this case I am trying to get an aggregated score for profile completion.  Thus if the user has completed these DB fields, he will have a total score of 5.  I hope that clarifies, thanks.

Comment: use `delimiter $$` before `BEGIN`... and instead of  `END` use `END$$`

Comment: @Jacques if I understand correctly you don't need to use `SUM`, just use + to get the score sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM` takes a single argument (/ column) which it sums across multiple rows, not multiple arguments (/ columns) for a single row, this is why it's not working.

This should work:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN first_name > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN last_name  > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN country    > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN state      > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN city       > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM employee_profile     
WHERE id = user_id_in;
```

Comment: This syntax is 100% accurate but I doubt it provides a meaningful piece of info. Let's see if @Jacques explains what he wants to do.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario From his explanation in the comments, it appears that this is what he wants.

Comment: So he wanted the number of non-empty cells after all... Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query this will suerly help you..

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE 
    WHEN first_name  = ''  THEN '1'
    WHEN last_name  = ''  THEN '1'
    WHEN country  = '' THEN '1'
    WHEN state  = '' THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
  END) AS total
FROM employee_profile     
    WHERE id = user_id_in;
```